# Galois group of $s^6 - t - 1$ in $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, function-fields

I was wondering how one would determine the galois group of the extension $\mathbb{F}_p(t,s)$ of $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$, where $s^6 = t + 1$? I certainly know (and Magma reassures) that this depends on the prime $p$ being congruent to 1 modulo 6 or not. If $p \equiv 1 \mod 6$, then $\mathbb{F}_p$ contains a sixth root of unity, so we for example have the automorphism sending s $\to$ $\xi_6s$ and t $\to$ t right? Does this generate the entire galois group?

I am quite rusty with Galois theory over function fields, so any hints\help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If $p=1\bmod 6$ then $\Bbb{F}_p(t,s)/\Bbb{F}_p(t)$ is Galois of degree $6$ with Galois group generated by the automorphism of order 6 you gave.

Comment: If $p\equiv-1\pmod6$ then the extension is not Galois, but you do get a normal closure with a quadratic extension of the field of constants. If $p=2$ or $3$ then the extension is not separable, and we get a headache.

Comment: Thank you both! I will work this out :)